# Jest Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, jestjs

I am trying to use Jest to test my node API. I have a simple npm script which calls jest

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "precommit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@koa/cors": "^2.2.1",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.4",
    "apollo-server-koa": "^1.3.6",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "graphql-tools": "^3.0.4",
    "koa": "^2.5.1",
    "koa-bodyparser": "^4.2.1",
    "koa-router": "^7.4.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "jest": "^23.3.0",
    "lint-staged": "^7.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5",
    "prettier": "^1.13.7"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "gitDir": "./",
    "*.{js,json}": [
      "prettier --no-semi --print-width 140 --tab-width 2 --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "bail": true,
    "verbose": true,
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/**/*.test.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a jest config in my `package.json` which tells jest what to test:

```
"jest": {
    "bail": true,
    "verbose": true,
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/**/*.test.js"
    ]
  }
```

I am not using babel at all in my project but for some reason when I try run my one test in `./test.test.js`

```
test("Example test", () => {
  expect(true).toBe(true)
})
```

I get the following error:

```
$ jest
 FAIL  ./test.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "/Users/<myusername>/Projects"

      at node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at OptionManager.resolvePresets (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
      at OptionManager.mergePresets (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)
      at OptionManager.mergeOptions (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)
      at OptionManager.init (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
      at File.initOptions (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
      at new File (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
      at Pipeline.transform (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.563s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have tried adding a babel env preset but still getting the same error. I don't think I should have to add a babel config just for testing either.

I am running node version `8.11.3` and yarn `1.7.0` and have jest installed locally in the project using version `^23.2.0`

How do I tell jest not to worry about babel env?

Comment: Are you the project doesn't declare any `.babelrc` file? It would be useful to provide at least your `package.json`.

Comment: @AndreaCarraro Don't quite understanding your question sorry. If you are asking if I have a `.babelrc` file, the answer is no. I have tried adding one in but I get the same error. I do not want to transpile my code any way so shouldn't need babel at all. I have added in my full package.json.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`babel-jest` is added automatically when you install Jest. If you don't intend to transpile ES6 code (seems like your case) maybe just reset the config:

```
// package.json
{
  "jest": {
    "transform": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my jest config `"jest": {
    "bail": true,
    "verbose": true,
    "transform": {},
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/**/*.test.js"
    ]
  }` but still getting the same error

Comment: Strange. Is the `testEnvironment` set to `node` by the way?

Comment: I don't believe so. You mean with the flag `--NODE_ENV=node`?

Comment: I have tried this again after having a break from the code over the weekend and setting `"transform": {}` is now resolving the issue. Not sure what I was doing wrong on the first attempt. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when you forget to add the babel-preset-env dependency.

As you have already said that you tried this solution, try to see if it is some specific version of babel-preset-env.

Which version are you using?

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: I was using `current` which would be node version 8.11.3. But why would jest need `babel-preset-env`. I can understand if I am using features which aren't supported in my current version of node but I am not.